# All .onion domains seem slow

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services

Is it just me or are most .onion domains really slow?

If its not just me then why is it slow?

Alot of domains seem to not work and a few work and are really slow...

Comment: Define slow? Do you have any speed tests? Onion sites have very high latency by design, so this is probably normal.

Comment: If a page load takes less than 10 seconds you're doing really well.

Answer (score 3):

.onion addresses are served using Tor Hidden Services and are known to be high-latency. There have been efforts to [Speed Up Tor Hidden Services](http://tor.hermetix.org/projects/hidserv.html) but they're still generally slower than "external" websites.

Answer (score 1):

The NLnet Project: Speed Up Tor Hidden Services is a old project (2008 - 2009). You canot prevent loops but you can inprove the web server return. Did you try to serve hidden services using apache httpd, Nginx, Lighty or node.js?

Did you see and aply articles like 
https://servercheck.in/blog/3-small-tweaks-make-apache-fly

Comment: This question is about hidden services being slow for clients, not about how to speed them up on the server-side.